# Intermittent Websphere application JVM crash due to GC assertion failed

Tags: java, jvm, garbage-collection, websphere, openj9

We hosted a java application in websphere 9 / jre 1.8.
Intermittently JVM crash and generating the javacore.
We are getting below error in java core , assertion failure error.

```
j9mm.141 - * ** ASSERTION FAILED ** AT LargeObjectAllocateStats.cpp:1126: ((false))**

GC History :
j9mm.621 - GC Assertion message: Calculated value of getSizeClassIndex() 133 can not be larger then maximum 122

j9mm.465 - CopyForward start

min heap size : 2GB
max heap size : 4GB
used heap size : 2GB at the time of GC
GC policy : balanced
```

Comment: Is it possible that you are using the OpenJ9 JVM?

Comment: We are using IBM Websphere bundled jvm

Comment: I found https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/IV61966 which suggests that the issue only occurs when `-Xgc:tlhMinimumSize=…` is used with a value `>512`. Though this issue is supposed to be fixed, but maybe, it’s a regression.

Comment: But we don’t have this jvm parameter set in our application

Comment: Maybe it’s helpful to tag the question with `openj9`, to attract the attention of readers with more experience in this area.

Comment: You should provide exact JVM version (output of command: java -version). You should check server.xml in your was profile folder for values of -Xgc:thlInitialSize and -Xgc:tlhMinimumSize. If not set standard values are 2048 and 512. You should install latest patches to WAS as that will install newer JVM. There are couple of APARs with this error and they all have been resolved in 2014.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an existing GitHub issue, so I think your best bet would be to [open a new user raised issue](https://github.com/eclipse-openj9/openj9/issues) so that GC devs can triage it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33407072)